# Error with opt/downloads, but opt/downloads does not exist

Tags: 20.04, compiling

I am attempting to build an image, but I get the below error. There is no opt/downloads folder.

```
Traceback (most recent call lunbunty ast):
ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable do_fetch[file-checksums], 
expression was ${@bb.fetch.get_checksum_file_list(d)}
${@get_lic_checksum_file_list(d)} which triggered exception
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/downloads'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a build-specific issue, depending on what/how you're building. If you create the directory, will things work properly?

```
sudo mkdir /opt/downloads
sudo chown {user}:{group} /opt/downloads
```

(Be sure to change `{user}` and `{group}` to the proper values for the account that is being used to build the image.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried changing the permissions and I also tried making the directory but this error persists: 


chown: changing ownership of '/opt': Operation not permitted

and

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/downloads’: Permission denied

Comment: Be sure to prefix those commands I offered with `sudo`, as `root` will own the location.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that before. Thank you. That fixed it!